# R shiny: save data frames from multiple panels

Tags: r, shiny

In the following app, I would like to add a global button, to save the tables in the 2 panels at the same time.
Ideally, they should be saved to an xlsx file, in tabs named after the corresponding tabs.
Please note that the tabs were created using a module.

Many thanks!!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

modDtUi <- function(id){ # UI module
  ns = NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns('x1'))
}


modDt <-  function(input, output, session, data, globalSession){ # Server module
  
  x <- data
  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(x, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('x1', session = globalSession)
  

  
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
    
      tabPanel("Table1", modDtUi("editable")),
      tabPanel("Table2", modDtUi("editable2"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(modDt,"editable", data = head(iris,10), globalSession = session)
  
  callModule(modDt,"editable2", data = tail(iris,5), globalSession = session)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this demo works.

I used `reactiveValues` `v$data` to store the data inside the module. The module will `return` `v$data` so it can be retrieved when you want to save the data in the shiny `server`.

I also added an `observeEvent` to detect changes in the data, and update the data table with `replaceData`.

The excel file is created using the `writexl` library, but you could substitute with others of course.

Let me know if this works for you. I imagine there are some elements of this answer that can be improved upon - and if we can identify them, would like to edit further.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(writexl)

modDtUi <- function(id){ # UI module
  ns = NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns(id))
}

modDt <-  function(input, output, session, data, id, globalSession){ # Server module
  
  v <- reactiveValues(data = data)
  
  output[[id]] <- DT::renderDataTable(v$data, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy(id, session = globalSession)
  
  id_input = paste(id, "cell_edit", sep = "_")
  
  # Could add observeEvent here to detect edit event
  observeEvent(input[[id_input]], {
    info = input[[id_input]]
    if (!is.null(info)) {
      v$data[info$row, info$col] <<- DT::coerceValue(info$value, v$data[info$row, info$col])
    }
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
  return(data = reactive({v$data}))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      actionButton("btn", "Save Both")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table1", modDtUi("editable1")),
        tabPanel("Table2", modDtUi("editable2"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  e1 <- callModule(modDt, "editable1", data = head(iris,10), id = "editable1", globalSession = session)
  e2 <- callModule(modDt, "editable2", data = tail(iris,5), id = "editable2", globalSession = session)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    print("Saving...")
    sheets <- list("e1" = e1(), "e2" = e2())
    write_xlsx(sheets, "test.xlsx")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like charm, and I could easily adapt it to my full script.